# Python Numpy: Random Seed

Tags: python, numpy, random

```py
num= 100
obs=[]
np.random.seed(1)

for i in range(num):
  
  N=[]
  CF3_1=[]
  CF3_2=[]
  i=2

  salvage= np.random.triangular(salvage_min, salvage_mode, salvage_max)
  inv= np.random.uniform(inv_min, inv_max)

  for y in range(0,5):
    
    gt= 14.747101 + 11.664259 * np.random.beta(0.645868, 0.920589)
    print(gt)
```

I am trying to get gt to start with np.random.seed(1) but it seems like gt does not start with seed 1.

```
np.random.seed(1)
gt= 14.747101 + 11.664259 * np.random.beta(0.645868, 0.920589)
print(gt)
```

produces a result of:

```
17.889105013452703
14.747134750650536
19.474766202077234
16.967191836499126
18.465043981244925
18.03420202040634
15.794033025059752
```

while the result of my code is:

```
14.747134750650536
19.474766202077234
16.967191836499126
18.465043981244925
18.03420202040634
```

Notice that the result of my code is the exact same, only that it skipped 17.889105013452703.

Comment: not sure what the issue is, as I ran your code without the salvage part and got 17... , and when I ran the couple lines and got the same value. explicitly write the code for the two cases which give the two different results. I suspect it is a problem with the code, as opposed to the seed.

Comment: I think it's the salvage and inv that's affecting the random seed. I had to do a scenario without salvage value, and so I didn't include that salvage and inv lines, and got the same value. Any idea on why random seed would affect the next line or how I could get "gt" to start at 17?

Comment: quite obvious when @craigb outlined the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected.  `np.random.triangular` and `np.random.uniform` each consume a random double (64 bits), while `np.random.beta` consumes two doubles; see [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1995e2cdfd17ec75e37cc6e69a42ce9000aac966/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c).

So after you reset the seed, calling `np.random.triangular` and `np.random.uniform` once each will consume two doubles, which means the values returned by successive `np.random.beta` calls will be one value behind what it returns without those two prior calls.

If you want your `gt` sequence to start with `np.random.seed(1)` then you should call `np.random.seed(1)` after you've called the other functions that consume random values (ie, before the inner `for` loop).

If you want `np.random.triangular` and `np.random.uniform` to generate random values (ie, not be repeatable due to `np.random.seed(1)`) you should create a separate random generator to use with them.

Comment: can't believe I did not see this when I removed those statements. thumbsup.